# Appendix labeling

Tags: sectioning, equations, numbering, appendix

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

As shown in Appendix~\ref{app_eg},...

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\section{An example}
\label{app_eg}

\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\label{pert}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I would like the name of the appendix to be Appendix A: An example. But the equation number and referencing in the main text should remain as it is now. Please suggest a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Update `\@seccntformat` to prefix the usual `\the<cntr>` with `Appendix`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

As shown in Appendix~\ref{app_eg},...

\appendix
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Appendix \csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\section{An example}
\label{app_eg}

\begin{equation}
  1+1=2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```